# NGINX proxy_pass to defined upstream instead of https url directly

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have an nginx config that looks similar to this (simplified):

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        location /api {
            proxy_pass https://my-bff.azurewebsites.net;
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, I have a reverse proxy to an API endpoint that uses https.

Now, I would like to convert this to an upstream group to gain access to keepalive and other features. So I tried this:

```
http {
    upstream bff-app {
        server my-bff.azurewebsites.net:443;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;


        location /api {
            proxy_pass https:/bff-app;
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        }
    }
}
```

Yet it doesn't work. Clearly I'm missing something.

In summary, how do I correctly do this "conversion" i.e. from url to defined upstream?

I have tried switching between http instead of https in the proxy_pass directive, but that didn't work either.

I was honestly expecting this to be a simple replacement. One upstream for another, but I'm doing something wrong it seems.

Comment: Try renaming the upstream label from `bff-app` to `my-bff.azurewebsites.net`, so that the `proxy_pass` statement appears the same.

Comment: @RichardSmith will it not just bypass the upstream and use the url? How can I tell if it's actually using the upstream?

Comment: Nginx will check the address against its upstream names before resorting to DNS. Don't know how you confirm this though.

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks. I did as you suggested and it worked. After further reading I switched back to the old label, and instead manually set the Host header to the correct domain i.e. "proxy_set_header Host my-bff.azurewebsites.net", which also solved the issue. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith) pointed me in the right direction.

Essentially, the issue was that the host header was being set to "bff-app" instead of "my-bff.azurewebsites.net" and this caused the remote server to close the connection.

Fixed by specifying header manually like below:

```
http {
    upstream bff-app {
        server my-bff.azurewebsites.net:443;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        location /api {
            proxy_pass https:/bff-app;
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
            # Manually set Host header to "my-bff.azurewebsites.net",
            # otherwise it will default to "bff-app".
            proxy_set_header Host my-bff.azurewebsites.net; 
        }
    }
}
```